# FFTing signal gives a strange output

Tags: fft

I've got an Intensity array and corresponding time array.

The intensity array has this shape: **I_n=[real0, img0, real1, img1...,]** and **time_n=[t1,t2...,tn]**, and am DFT-ing the Intensity (**I**).

I am not sure if this is obvious, but there is no requirement to input time values in the function, I just included the **I** array. I get an object of this shape **{ re:[...], im:[...] }**

If I get the idea correctly, FTs do **I (t) --> I (f)**. I am plotting the real part and complex part vs time (though I thought the imaginary part is non-important), expecting to at least get the right shape (some peaks). Instead I get a plot that looks pretty much like a spectra (with peaks) but some of those peaks are negative.

Is there any clear error here? I can't wrap my hear around it so far.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGVO0.png]

Comment: You probably want to plot the *magnitude* of the complex frequency domain values (`sqrt(re^2+im^2)`). This is not really a programming question though - for more help you might want to try https://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @PaulR indeed that's what ii did, followed by removing half of each plot bc they are/seem mirror images when plotted. Thanks